# Select Item in Polymer 2 paper-dropdown-menu with TAB

Tags: html, polymer

I have a paper-dropdown-menu in Polymer 2, similar to this one:

```
<paper-dropdown-menu label="Dinosaurs">
  <paper-listbox class="dropdown-content" selected="1">
    <paper-item>allosaurus</paper-item>
    <paper-item>brontosaurus</paper-item>
    <paper-item>carcharodontosaurus</paper-item>
    <paper-item>diplodocus</paper-item>
  </paper-listbox>
</paper-dropdown-menu>
```

I can select an item of the paper-listbox by pressing the ENTER- Key on my Keyboard. Is there a way to select a paper-item by pressing the Tab key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a key binding to `<paper-listbox>` via [`addOwnKeyBinding()`](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/paper-listbox/paper-listbox#method-addOwnKeyBinding). The specified handler must be a method of `<paper-listbox>`, so you'd have to attach your own method.

```
<paper-listbox id="listbox></paper-listbox>

// script
connectedCallback() {
  super.connectedCallback();

  // Attach our own handler for TAB-key
  this.$.listbox._onListTabKey = e => {

    // Cancel TAB key event
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.detail.keyboardEvent.preventDefault();

    // Select currently focused item
    const focusedIndex = this.$.listbox.indexOf(this.$.listbox.focusedItem);
    this.$.listbox.select(focusedIndex);
  };

  this.$.listbox.addOwnKeyBinding('tab', '_onListTabKey');
}
```

<sup>[Polymer 1 demo](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/yMzJbZ?editors=1010)</sup>

<sup>[Polymer 2 demo](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/MpEeOR?editors=1010)</sup>

Note overriding <kbd>TAB</kbd> may be an accessibility issue.

Comment: Thank you Tony, thats exactly what i was searching for. :)

Comment: @TobiasB No problem :)